# Converting optparse to argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, optparse

Using optparse, I currently have:

```
opts, args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

which is then feeding into a function that accepts opts:

```
func(opts,sys.argv)
```

I'm trying to now use argparse, but the formatting for argparse is different:

```
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

which doesn't allow me to feed the opts into the function.

I was wondering if there's any way to use argparse while maintaining opts to feed into the function.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 5):

The end of the `argparse` docs page describes the basic differences.

```
opts, args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

In `optparse`, all flagged arguments are captured in the `opts` variable.  Everything else is in the `args` list.

In `argparse`, both flagged (also called optionals) and positionals are collected in the `args` Namespace

`parse_known_args` gives an output that is closer to `optparse`:

```
args, extras = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

`extras` are strings that it can't parse; roughly corresponding to the 2nd variable returned by `optparse`.

Fire up an interactive shell, define a couple of parsers, and play with the different arguments.  And of course print the outputs ('opts','args','extras') to see what they produce.

If you have further questions, include sample parsers and outputs in your question.

---

```
In [3]: aparser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [4]: aparser.add_argument('-f');
In [5]: aparser.add_argument('bar');

In [6]: oparser=optparse.OptionParser()
In [7]: oparser.add_option('-f')
```

optparse parsing:

```
In [22]: opts, rest = oparser.parse_args('-f one two'.split())
In [23]: opts
Out[23]: <Values at 0xaca3a02c: {'f': 'one'}>
In [24]: rest
Out[24]: ['two']
In [25]: opts.f
Out[25]: 'one'
```

argparse parsing

```
In [26]: args = aparser.parse_args('-f one two'.split())
In [27]: args
Out[27]: Namespace(bar='two', f='one')
In [28]: args.f
Out[28]: 'one'
In [29]: args.bar
Out[29]: 'two'
```

parse_known_args:

```
In [30]: args, extras = aparser.parse_known_args('-f one two three'.split())
In [31]: args
Out[31]: Namespace(bar='two', f='one')
In [32]: extras
Out[32]: ['three']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `argparse` in a very similar way to `optparse`. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags) you can see that you just need to prefix arguments with either `-` or `--` and it becomes an optional parameter.

Here's an example from the documentation:

```python
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')
parser.add_argument('bar')
args = parser.parse_args
```

Additionally, you can change the [prefix chars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars) if your program needs to have options that are prefixed by different charaters:

```python
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars='+')
parser.add_argument('+f', '++foo')
parser.add_argument('bar')
args = parser.parse_args
```